# I'm getting Wrong item when clicking listview after filtering it

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using an example from JoeRock's Channel.The problem exist when i'm using item click event after filtering listview

Here is my Class:

```
class Friend
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Here is My Friends adapter

```
class FriendsAdapter : BaseAdapter<Friend>
{
    private Context mContext;
    private int mRowLayout;
    private List<Friend> mFriends;


    public FriendsAdapter(Context context, int rowLayout, List<Friend> friends)
    {
        mContext = context;
        mRowLayout = rowLayout;
        mFriends = friends;

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return mFriends.Count; }
    }

    public override Friend this[int position]
    {
        get { return mFriends[position]; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mRowLayout, parent, false);
        }


        TextView firstName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtFirstName);
        firstName.Text = mFriends[position].FirstName;

        TextView lastName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLastName);
        lastName.Text = mFriends[position].LastName;

        TextView age = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtAge);
        age.Text = mFriends[position].Age;

        TextView gender = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtGender);
        gender.Text = mFriends[position].Gender;



        return row;
    }
```

And Here is my activity

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
        mSearch = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etSearch);
        mContainer = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.llContainer);

        mTxtHeaderFirstName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderFirstName);
        mTxtHeaderLastName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderLastName);
        mTxtHeaderAge = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderAge);
        mTxtHeaderGender = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHeaderGender);


        mSearch.Alpha = 0;
        mContainer.BringToFront();

        mSearch.TextChanged += mSearch_TextChanged;

        mFriends = new List<Friend>();
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Bob", LastName = "Smith", Age = "33", Gender = "Male" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Smith", Age = "45", Gender = "Male" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Julie", LastName = "Smith", Age = "2020", Gender = "Unknown" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Molly", LastName = "Smith", Age = "21", Gender = "Female" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Lopez", Age = "22", Gender = "Male" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Ruth", LastName = "White", Age = "81", Gender = "Female" });
        mFriends.Add(new Friend { FirstName = "Sally", LastName = "Johnson", Age = "54", Gender = "Female" });

        mAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.row_friend, mFriends);
        mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;

         mListView.ItemClick += Mlistview_ItemClick;//The Problem is Here:

    }
    private void Mlistview_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
       string test = mFriends[e.Position].FirstName;
        Toast.MakeText(this, test, ToastLength.Short).Show();


    }


    void mSearch_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Friend> searchedFriends = (from friend in mFriends
                                        where friend.FirstName.Contains(mSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || friend.LastName.Contains(mSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                        || friend.Age.Contains(mSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || friend.Gender.Contains(mSearch.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                        select friend).ToList<Friend>();

        //Refreshes the listview
        mAdapter = new FriendsAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.row_friend, searchedFriends);
        mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
    }
```

The Problem is that, when my listview is filtered from a searchBox and i'm choosing an item it doesnt show me the right name, but the name which exist in mitems in my specific list position.

I dont know how can be fixed this. Any answer are accepted even for java. I just need a solution for solving this. Look Pictures below

**Here Code works right**
[image: Here Code works right]

**Here i'm taking wrong Name**
[image: Here i'm taking wrong Name]

I read that i must create a RecyclerView.Adapter.Is it right? how can do this?

Comment: you are referencing mFriends which is your global variable... You will need to retrieve the value in your listview

Comment: An help for how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
string test = mFriends[e.Position].FirstName;
```

with

```
string test = ((Friend)mAdapter.GetItem(e.Position)).FirstName;
```

Reason for this is that at text changed event you are creating new Adapter with a new list. This list is available in mAdapter.

Comment: Thank you for answer but i'm facing error Object doesnt contain definition fo FirstName.

Comment: Try casting the object you get from GetItem to a Friend object and then get the first name

Comment: Can you give me an example of how can i do that?